# Calling methods in pharo smalltalk

Tags: oop, methods, smalltalk, pharo

I'm trying to call a function from another class (Binario) but it says it's not implemented.

This is the code for the method in Binario class:

```
  genlista
  ^ (1 to: 30) collect: [ :i | 2 atRandom - 1 ]
```

And this is the code for the other class method:

```
 ListadelistasBin
  | bin |
  bin := Binario new.
  ^ (1 to: 30) collect: [ :i | bin genlista ]
```

Please, help me :(

Comment: Are you sure that the `genlista` method is implemented in the `Binario` class on the instance side? Do you see the the `genlista` method in the output of `Binario  methodDict`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely @Uko is right and you defined the method in the class side of `Binario` rather than in the instance side. One way to check this would be to modify your second method like this:

```
ListadelistasBin
  | bin |
  bin := Binario.                            "<- new removed"
  ^ (1 to: 30) collect: [:i | bin genlista]
```

If now you get the answer, then what happened is that your `genlista` method is in the wrong place (class side instead of instance side).

In Smalltalk every method belongs in a class. However, there are two "sides" of a class. The *instance* side is where you put methods for the instances of the class. The *class* side is where you put methods for the class itself.

How can you tell in what side of a class you have saved a method? Just look for the switch that every browser has to select one or the other side. In Pharo, for example, there is a toggle button that you use to select each of the sides.

While instance methods define the behavior of the instance of your class (and subclasses), class methods are meant to be sent to the class. This is just a consequence of classes being objects. For example, `Binario new` is a message sent to the class `Binario`, and we believe that your intention was to define the `genlista` method for instances of `Binario`. If this is the case, then copy the source code of the method and paste it on the instance side of the class. Then remove the class method and try again. Ah! and don't forget to put the `new` message back next to `Binario` in your `ListadelistasBin`!

Comment: Thanks! Is that side class where I should implement the constructor method?

Comment: Also most Smalltalk IDEs will have a right-click menu on the method which will allow you to refactor and "Move to instance side". (Pharo does)

Comment: @DianaAyala I would save the `genlista` method in the instance side of the class. To do that, just move the method from the class to the instance side (as explained in my answer).